# How to clear screen in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to know that how can I clear console screen in java.
The IDE I am using is IntelliJ IDEA.
For example: In C language we use to write: clrscr();

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in IntelliJ as the console is not a real terminal.

There are however different console plugins where this is possible. One of which is the [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console).

Comment: Perhaps you could have named one or two of these plugins?

Comment: As Gabriele wrote: The Grep Console is the most commonly used

Comment: Yes, but if you noted the times of my comment and the edit that added the plugin, my comment came first.